# Hacked asp.net dnn site

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, dotnetnuke, firewall

I'm have dotNetNuke website.
Somebody upload "i.htm" file to my website files folder.
In file wrote about "Mr.Kro0oz.305".
I'm can't understand how can be done that.
So you hove some versions how can do it by hackers?
Also how can set my server more secure?

Comment: Do you have an upload functionality in your site, maybe for a profile picture? Does DNN have such a feature that a user (with DNN experience) might access, even though you don't have a specific page for it? Try and make sure a user can only upload specific file types.

Comment: The file which is uploaded by hacker in wwwroot -> site root folder.
Also in site there are uploads parts. Also I have watched some videos where Mr.Kro0oz.305 hacking sites using some shell command in linux.

Comment: Which folder? The root, /Portals, /Portals/{PortalID}. But at least change all your Admin, Host & FTP passwords.

Comment: While DNN could be at fault here, many times this is due to a vulnerability in IIS or Windows that you haven't closed with the proper windows updates.

Comment: The file in this path: D:\inetpub\wwwroot\fsm\i.htm. In this server don't set FTP. I don't now where is my mistake, may be it come from IIS or windows update. But I think that hacker all done using linux commands to upload, changing or removing files.

Comment: There are other websites infected in your server? Or that is the only one?

Comment: It is only one.

Comment: Googling `Mr.Kro0oz.305` gives a lot of results (of hacked sites?). As Chris Hammond suggests it looks more like a server hack than a DNN specific one. Is it your own server or a 3rd party hoster?

Comment: Yes I'm tell that my site is DNN, but this hacker's hacked sites more PHP sites. This server my. I thing It use some shell commands which can hack my host files.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at this page - https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/155449/critical-security-update--september2017

There is a huge security flaw in DNN for versions prior to DNN9 that allows users to exploit the Telerik dialog handler to allow them to upload documents anywhere in your website, and potentially exploit it further to access the entire drive.

You should install the security patch in the link above, as well as the security analyzer, but to be safe you really need to keep upgrading DNN to the latest version.